# get "user_id" along with the AccessToken from Django-Tastypie Server

Tags: ios, django, oauth, oauth-2.0, django-authentication

My server is Django-Tastypie REST server which is accessed by an iOS client. I want to implement OAuth2 for authentication. I'm currently using this: https://github.com/caffeinehit/django-oauth2-provider and on the client side I am using AFNetworking 2.0 AFHTTPRequestOperationManager to handle the request and response. I'm following [this](http://blog.ingenuity.ph/2013/08/connecting-ios-app-to-django-tastypie.html) tutorial (which I updated to work with AFNetworking 2.0). Now, following the tutorial, everything works well, I am able to get the "access_token" for a user by passing a HTTPRequest with values CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, username and password in its body.

The response I get is:

```
{"access_token": "<your-access-token>", "scope": "read", "expires_in": 86399, "refresh_token": "<your-refresh-token>"}
```

Uptil now, the tutorial worked great, but further on it is showed that the author also gets a `"user_id"` field in the response along with the above fields. And he then stores the `"access_token"` and `"user_id"` in the iOS client. Then to retrieve a resource from the server, he creates a custom HTTPRequest with "Authorization" field and `"access_token"` in the header and sends it to a URL which he creates by using the `"user_id"` which he had saved.

Now, my problem is that I searched everywhere and haven't found a way to get the `"user_id"` in that response. How can I generate a request URL for fetching a resource(like in the tutorials) if I don't know the "user_id"? OR How am I supposed to identify the resource I want to get using only the "access_token"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was very dumb of me to not use the "username" itself (which I had entered earlier to get the "access_token") to identify the resource. I changed the resource API lookup to use "username" in the URL instead of "user_id" and it worked perfectly!